# ruby activerecord find optimizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this in my code:

```
area_code_rec = @phone.area_codes.find_by_areacode(area_code)
```

It was brought to my attention that this may be more rails 3 like, but then
I am not sure if active record optimizes as the where() part should return
a full array or does it look at the rest of the statement and not do that ?

```
area_code_rec = @phone.area_codes.select(:id).where(:areacode => area_code).last
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: apparently it does optimize with lazy evaluation because otherwise this part returns an array: @phone.area_codes.select(:id).where(:areacode => area_code) 
I don't want the array just the last element as above. If it built the whole array in memory this would be inefficient as the code is in a critical area that gets executed many times

Comment: Update your question with more explicit details and people with answer.